# How do I make my selection sort code allow the user to input their own values

Tags: java, sorting

I want to let the user input their own values, this is what I have for this selection sort code

```
public class SelectionSort {

public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] arr = {5,4,3,2,1}; // This is my array
    int min = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        //Assume first element is min
        min = i;
        for(int j = i + 1;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] < arr[min]) { min = j;}
        }
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[min];
        arr[min] = temp;
        System.out.println(arr[i]);//I print the in ascending order 
    }
}

}
```

Comment: So...where's your `Scanner` at?

Answer (score -1):

Add below part in you code :

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("No of elements : ");
    int noOfElements  =sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr =  new int[noOfElements];

    System.out.println("Give elements : ");
    for(int i=0;i<noOfElements;i++){
        arr[i]= sc.nextInt();   
    }
```

Your final code will be as below :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SelectionSort {

public static void main(String args[]){
   // int[] arr = {5,4,3,2,1}; // This is my array
    int min = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("No of elements : ");
    int noOfElements  =sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr =  new int[noOfElements];

    System.out.println("Give elements : ");
    for(int i=0;i<noOfElements;i++){
        arr[i]= sc.nextInt();


    }


    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        //Assume first element is min
        min = i;
        for(int j = i + 1;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] < arr[min]) { min = j;}
        }
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[min];
        arr[min] = temp;
        System.out.println("Sorted Elemenst : "+arr[i]);//I print the in ascending order 
    }
}
}
```